# Use a reference to the same object inside an object

Tags: swagger-2.0, swagger-editor

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
User:
    type: "object"
    properties:
      id:
        type: "integer"
        format: "int64"
      name:
        type: "string"
      manager:
        $ref: "/definitions/User"
```

Editor does not throw an exception, but the code generated according to this schema does not work at all.

I generated python-flask server, and on launch, it throws:
`ImportError: cannot import name 'User'`

Looking through the code I found that 'User' class uses 'User' keyword in `__init__` and inside the class.

Also there was the import: `from swagger_server.models.user import User`

Does python-flask generator know how to implement references like this?

Comment: Can you explain in more details what you mean by "generated code does not work"? Is the generated code incorrect? Do you get errors? Something else? Also, which exactly code did you generate (e.g. `aspnetcore` server or `java` client)?

Comment: I'm sorry, of course.
I generate python-flask server, and on launch, it throws `ImportError: cannot import name 'User'`
Looking through the code I found that 'User' class uses 'User' keyword in __init__ and inside the class. And also I've noticed `from  swagger_server.models.user import User` in imports.

It looks strange, I guess python-flask generator does not know how to implement references like this.

Comment: [Edit] the question and put all details about what you are trying to do, what you tried, and what results you get into the question. Comments can be deleted.

Comment: [It's a bug](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues/8677) in the python-flask generator.